# Objects dissapearing when I press Render, then reappearing after a short time if I go back to 3d view port

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: Before Render]

Before I render, this is the screen I have, all objects as they should be.
When I hit render, the clothes don't render, only the body.

When I cancel the render, as it's not rendering what I want it to render, this is the 3D view port image I get:

[image: After Pressing Render]

After a few seconds, the body reappears and it's back to the original image.

Any idea why for some reason it's almost inverted? The Rendered image ONLY shows the Body, then the standard 3D view port will only show the clothes?

The wall is present in both.

I use cycles render, if it helps.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. Your images are broken while it's easy to upload them here

Comment: check that the eye and camera icons in the outliner are enabled on both objects.